# Making nice snippet from URL parse (like in WhatsApp, Viber, Skype)

Tags: parsing, url, youtube, preview

We have chat on our site and want to improve it. Users are often sending each other links to news sites, articles, YouTube videos etc

We want to convert those links to nice images with some info, aka "snippets"
Here are examples

Example, facebook chat: http://c2n.me/3z442bv.jpg
Skype: http://c2n.me/3z44a60.jpg

but it means to program own parser that is complicated task. Are there any ready libraries, sites providing such a service?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use open graph parser
for example(Open graph parser in JQuery) and you can find many other parsers
https://github.com/fiann/jquery.ogp


Nowadays Mostly every website uses open graph tags.

**Edit**
(Plugin code from above github repository)

```
    (function($) {

  var checkNamespacePresent = function (node) {
    console.log("Checking for namespace on node", node);
    var i, attr, attributes = node.attributes || {};
    // we're looking for xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
    for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
      attr = attributes[i];
      if (attr.nodeName.substring(0,5) === "xmlns" && 
          attr.nodeValue === "http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/") {
        return attr.nodeName.substring(6);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  $.fn.ogp = function() {
    var ns = null, data = {};
    $(this).each(function () {
      $(this).parents().andSelf().each(function () {
        ns = checkNamespacePresent(this);
        console.log("Found %s on", ns, this);
        if (ns !== null) {
          return false;
        } 
      });

      // give up if no namespace
      if (ns === null) {
        console.log("No namespace found");
        return null;
      }

      // look for OGP data
      ns = ns + ":";
      $('meta', this).each(function () {
        console.log("Looking for data in element", this);
        var prop = $(this).attr("property"), key, value;
        if (prop && prop.substring(0, ns.length) === ns) {
          key = prop.substring(ns.length);
          value = $(this).attr("content");
          console.log("Found OGP data %s=%s", key, value);
          data[key] = data[key] || [];
          data[key].push(value);
        }
      });
    });

    // this is the total of everything
    console.log("All the data is ", data);

    return data;
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.